# How to reposition drop down menu in <select>

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have the following:

```
<select class="class1 class2 class3">
    <option> Long amount of text </option>
    <option> Long amount of text </option>
</select>
```

This renders a drop down menu but it is off screen, because of the length of the text and also because the drop down menu must be positioned to the far right of the screen.

How can I reposition the drop down menu so it isn't offscreen?
Or how can change the centre position of the drop down menu to be the top right instead of the top left?

Using float:  somehow blocks the drop down menu from rendering in my case.

This is basically what I want to do, move the menu to the right:

[image: What it looks like at the moment]

[image: What I want it to look like, move drop down menu to the right]

Comment: Please show all the relevant code so that we can see what you see.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do that.

Comment: Alright, thanks Clonkex

Comment: It is impossible without replacing it using javaScript.

Comment: While you have gotten your answer, in the future just post all your relevant code so we can reproduce your issue. The pictures are nice, but not needed if we have the code.